# Multiple DatePickers, force close when screen is rotated

Tags: android, datepicker, nullpointerexception, timepicker, screen-rotation

This is my first Android-app and prior to this I had no Java knowledge at all.

I used the following code ([found in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734981/multiple-datepickers-in-same-activity/4474007#4474007), by [Adam L.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/237820/adam-l)), I have 28 timepickers and it worked great after altering the code a bit.
But one thing I notice is that I get force close (nullpointerexception) when I am in a timepickerdialog (or datepickerdialog when using the code as it is displayed here) and change orientation of the screen.
I guess I need to save some info with onDestroy and restoring it again with onStart but I do not know how to accomplish this.
In my own code I use timepickerdialogs but [Adam L.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/237820/adam-l)s code is cleaner so solving the problem there would also solve my own problem.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MultiDatePickerActivity extends Activity {

private TextView startDateDisplay;
private TextView endDateDisplay;
private Button startPickDate;
private Button endPickDate;
private Calendar startDate;
private Calendar endDate;

static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;

private TextView activeDateDisplay;
private Calendar activeDate;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.multidatepicker);

    /*  capture our View elements for the start date function   */
    startDateDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.startDateDisplay);
    startPickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startPickDate);

    /* get the current date */
    startDate = Calendar.getInstance();

    /* add a click listener to the button   */
    startPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDateDialog(startDateDisplay, startDate);
        }
    });

    /* capture our View elements for the end date function */
    endDateDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.endDateDisplay);
    endPickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.endPickDate);

    /* get the current date */
    endDate = Calendar.getInstance();

    /* add a click listener to the button   */
    endPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDateDialog(endDateDisplay, endDate);
        }
    });

    /* display the current date (this method is below)  */
    updateDisplay(startDateDisplay, startDate);
    updateDisplay(endDateDisplay, endDate);
}

private void updateDisplay(TextView dateDisplay, Calendar date) {
    dateDisplay.setText(
            new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based so add 1
                .append(date.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1).append("-")
                .append(date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).append("-")
                .append(date.get(Calendar.YEAR)).append(" "));

}

public void showDateDialog(TextView dateDisplay, Calendar date) {
    activeDateDisplay = dateDisplay;
    activeDate = date;
    showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
}

private OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = new OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        activeDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        activeDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        activeDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        updateDisplay(activeDateDisplay, activeDate);
        unregisterDateDisplay();
    }
};

private void unregisterDateDisplay() {
    activeDateDisplay = null;
    activeDate = null;
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, dateSetListener, activeDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), activeDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), activeDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
    super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);
    switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            ((DatePickerDialog) dialog).updateDate(activeDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), activeDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), activeDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            break;
    }
}
}
```

I think this is the interesting part of the logcat in Eclipse:

```
12-18 11:32:52.415: INFO/ActivityManager(577): Displayed activity se.bergsland.manydatepickers/.ManyDatePickers: 993 ms
12-18 11:32:57.625: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1734): GC freed 1950 objects / 104136 bytes in 192ms
12-18 11:33:00.396: INFO/WindowManager(577): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=0/0 locale=en_US touch=3 key=2/1/2 nav=3 orien=2 }
12-18 11:33:00.535: DEBUG/StatusBar(577): updateResources
12-18 11:33:00.595: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(1763): Shutting down VM
12-18 11:33:00.595: WARN/dalvikvm(1763): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4000fe70)
12-18 11:33:00.605: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1763): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
12-18 11:33:00.615: INFO/WindowManager(577): onOrientationChanged, rotation changed to 0
12-18 11:33:00.625: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1763): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{se.bergsland.manydatepickers/se.bergsland.manydatepickers.ManyDatePickers}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-18 11:33:00.625: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2268)
12-18 11:33:00.625: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
12-18 11:33:00.625: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3278)
12-18 11:33:00.625: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:112)
12-18 11:33:00.625: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
12-18 11:33:00.625: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-18 11:33:00.625: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-18 11:33:00.625: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
12-18 11:33:00.625: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-18 11:33:00.625: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-18 11:33:00.625: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
12-18 11:33:00.625: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
12-18 11:33:00.625: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-18 11:33:00.625: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1763): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-18 11:33:00.625: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at se.bergsland.manydatepickers.ManyDatePickers.onCreateDialog(ManyDatePickers.java:102)
12-18 11:33:00.625: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at android.app.Activity.restoreManagedDialogs(Activity.java:857)
12-18 11:33:00.625: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:801)
12-18 11:33:00.625: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1172)
12-18 11:33:00.625: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1763):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
12-18 11:33:00.625: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1763):     ... 12 more
```

Comment: when orientation changes, createDialog gets called automatically. Hence the issue. Modify the logic to instantiate activeDate correctly.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to do this but this would be a better solution than using fargaths method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code in your Activity:

```
@Override

public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Use this in your manifest file:

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
```

Comment: <activity android:name="MyActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Does this mean that the activity is never destroyed? If so are there any negative results of solving it this way?

Answer (score 1):

Fargath's advice wasn't the best I'm afraid. Your problem is that `activateDate` is null when `onCreateDialog()` is called after a configuration change. Since you only set it once in `onClick()`. You need to set it in `onStart()`. Setting it in `onResume()` won't work, but you might need to set it there as well, see my problem [Android lifecycle: Fill in data in activity in onStart() or onResume()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636797/android-lifecycle-fill-in-data-in-activity-in-onstart-or-onresume).

If you want to update the dates at the exact moment that the dialog is being shown, then you can do a direct `Calendar.getInstance()` via `updateDate()` in `onPrepareDialog()`.

The problem with Fargath's solution is that you are hiding the soft keyboard, but the problem still exists on devices with a hardware keyboard such as the G1. The same goes for incoming phone calls. I'm not sure what `onConfigurationChanged()` has to do with it.