# Multiple Date-picker Dialog 

Tags: android, datepicker

I have 4 DatePicker Dialog in my Activity Class which are shown on click of 4 buttons . Now for these datePickerDialog i want to use same listener .

```
        DatePickerDialog taxPickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getCurrentContext(),dateSetListener,calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),calendar.get(Calendar.DATE));
        taxPickerDialog.show();

        DatePickerDialog fcPickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getCurrentContext(),dateSetListener,calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),calendar.get(Calendar.DATE));
        fcPickerDialog.show();
        break;

        DatePickerDialog expiryPickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getCurrentContext(),dateSetListener,calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),calendar.get(Calendar.DATE));
        expiryPickerDialog.show();


        DatePickerDialog permitPickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getCurrentContext(),dateSetListener,calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),calendar.get(Calendar.DATE));
        permitPickerDialog.show();
```

**Now i want a use listener but dnot know how to implement this ???**

```
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener =new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    switch(????){????}
}
};
```

Comment: Well for this you might like to see 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734981/multiple-datepickers-in-same-activity

Comment: maybe this approach could be useful for you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734981/multiple-datepickers-in-same-activity

Answer (score 0):

```
class DPlistener implements OnDateSetListener
{

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {

         //you can here
        if (view.equals(expiryPickerDialog))
        {
      //do needfull
              }
    }}
```

and register this listener in your datepicker views., make sure this class is inner class of your activity

Comment: Not working. While debugging ... if condition returns false .

Answer (score 0):

Hope you might have resolved this by now. Just putting an idea -  "you can set some sort of `ID` or `TAG` for `DatePicker` associated with each `Dialog` and then you can differentiate by querying what you have set `(ID/TAG)`."

Comment: Thanks for reply .. but this issue is still open . I cant use ID as i dnt have it because DatePicker is created on Java Code not on Xml ,

Comment: Mohit, you can add ID in code as well using View's setId() method.

Answer (score 0):

I know its a late reply but i went through with the same condition recently . So here is my answer ,

the

```
`DialogFragment.Show(FragmentManager manager, String tag))`
```

method is set tag for Fragment itself . so this tag can be use as follows :

```
Fragment dateTo=getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dateTo");
            if(dateTo!=null){
                //do something

            }
```

one use case is you can display more then one `Fragment` in a activity and to identify the fragment you can find that fragment with the given tag.If it is not null, bingo!!!