# Get instance of a Listener in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm implementing a Fragment that calls two `TimePickerDialog`'s as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15916863/6022725).

But that answer implements it in a activity and then uses a instance of the listener using

`mListener = getActivity() instanceof TimePickerDialogListener ? (TimePickerDialogListener)  getActivity()  : null;`

How can I get the Listener instance in my Fragment that implements the `TimePickerDialogListener`?

Comment: You don't use `getActivity()`, you use the instance of the Fragment

Comment: @cricket_007 how I get the instance of the Fragment?

Comment: Hard to tell without a [mcve] of your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To create a time picker**

If you simply want to use a time picker you can use `TimePickerDialog` and provide it with a `TimePickerDialogListener`

```
public void showTimePicker(int hour,int minute,boolean is24HourViews) {
        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hour, int minute) {
                        //Do your setup
                    }
                }, hour, minute,is24HourView);
        timePickerDialog.show(); //Show the dialog
}
```

Comment: THANKS! I've spend my entire afternoon trying to make this work with interfaces, another class and many others random things. You made it with one method! Thanks you so much!